# Kendo treeList datasource - not getting bound with remote data

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

I have written a directive for treeList and binding data to it from remote service call. Below is the code for TreeListDataSource in link method of directive:

```js
scope.treeListOptions.dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
  transport: {
    read: function(options) {
      scope.getData().then(function(dataToBeDisplayed) {
        options.success(dataToBeDisplayed);
      }, function(error) {
        $log.error(error);
      });
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert(e.status + e.errorThrown);
    },
  },
});

scope.treeListOptions.dataSource.read();
```

following is the TreeList directive definition:

```js
var TreeListDirectiveDefinition = {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  template: '<div><kendo-treelist k-options="treeListOptions"></kendo-treelist></div>',
  scope: {
    columns: '=',
    getMethod: '&'
  },
  link: linkTreeList
};
```

When i see the data bound to scope.treeListOptions.dataSource.data(), there are many new properties added as shown below:

```js
// parent element
C.define.init
PartExamined: "test"
StudyUid: "1.3.6.1.4.1.30071.8.56809868014.4964677242993979.234.56616"
_events: Object
_loaded: true
dirty: false
hasChildren: true
id: 1
parent: ()
parentId: null
parentIdField: "parentId"
uid: "1ca6302c-b1ad-493f-b002-d2032a548a80"
__proto__: i.extend.i


//child element
C.define.init
PartExamined: "test2"
SeriesInstanceUid: "1.3.6.1.4.1.30071.8.56809868014.4964677242993979.234.56617"
_events: Object
_loaded: true
dirty: false
hasChildren: false
id: 2
parent: ()
parentId: 1
parentIdField: "parentId"
uid: "953bc7a7-e5e8-4f26-a120-b13402c6cce4"
__proto__: i.extend.i
```

Properties like **parent: (), parentIdField: "parentId", _loaded: true, dirty: false, hasChildren: true** are added by the TreeListDataSource.

Is this the correct format for data? because the the TreeList is displaying **"No records to display"**.

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

**UPDATED**
Here is the link for angular directive created for treeList: http://jsfiddle.net/yuqorcvL/15/

The directive is still not work. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a `schema` in `scope.treeListOptions.dataSource`

```
schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "EmployeeID",
                            parentId: "ReportsTo",
                            fields: {
                                ReportsTo: { field: "ReportsTo",  nullable: true },
                                EmployeeID: { field: "EmployeeId", type: "number" },
                                Extension: { field: "Extension", type: "number" }
                            },
                            expanded: true
                        }
                    }
```

look [that example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index) at kendo docs

Comment: The example i created in this link works without schema: [link](http://dojo.telerik.com/akAwe/4). Any other solution?

Comment: What inside  `data`                                                                                                `var treeList = $("#treeList").data("kendoTreeList");
  var data = treeList.dataSource.data();`     ?

Comment: Data format in your post is correct. Additional fields are created by kendo `TreeListDataSource` wrapper.

Comment: @ Layonez Wronskey: The second code snippet in the question is what returned from treeList.dataSource.data(). Any solution?

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not working. You have wrong tags in it `ng:app` should be `ng-app`, `ng:controller` - `ng-controller`, ` myApp.directive('treeGrid'` - `myApp.directive('tree-grid'`